# Access list of bounced and undeliverable in Data Extension

Tags: email, dataextensions

In SFMC Email Studio I have Master Data Extension used to construct many other data extensions. When I open details for my Master DE and select Tracking tab I see the pie chart with four categories: Active, Bounced, Undeliverable, and Unsubscribed. For each category, there is percent share and number of records. Unfortunately, I don't see a way to view/export list of members of each of these categories? I need to find out which records as bounced and undeliverable according to SFMC. It would be great if I could request this information via API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can execute a query like below to retrieve the records and write them to a target DE:

```
SELECT SubscriberKey FROM ENT._Subscribers WHERE Status = 'Bounced'
```

Please change the value of "Bounced" with the values here based on your request:

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_subscribers_without_enhanced_subscriber_features.htm&type=5

Comment: You need to add a status column so u can get all of the status. Also if you want to get it by sends, you need to join through _Job, Sent, open and clicks. Lastly the ent. Prefix will only work in a child business unit in an enterprise account. If you are in the parent account it won’t work